# React mapping object key of the array to display as table's head failed

Tags: reactjs

I was trying to get the object key of the array to display as the header of table but failed with using map in react.
by using console.log, I was able to see it return the correct value it return blank on the HTML.

Here is my code

```
<tr>
{fileList.forEach((titleList) => {
      const title = [];
       title.push(Object.keys(titleList))
        // console.log(title) 
       title.map((item, key) => {
         // console.log(item)
           return <th key={key} scope="col">{item}</th>
        })
    })
}
</tr>
```

The json data was from here: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1/comments
Here is my full project code if you willing to check: https://codesandbox.io/s/dry-wave-gu0ns?file=/src/listPage/ListPage.js

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What ever you do inside forEach will not go to your JSX, even if you are returning inside the `map` inside `forEach`.

Either move the entire code to another function or try the below approach

```
<tr>
{fileList.map((titleList) => {
      const titles = Object.keys(titleList);
        // console.log(title) 
       return titles.map((item, key) => {
         // console.log(item)
           return <th key={key} scope="col">{item}</th>
        })
    })
}
</tr>
```

this way what ever retuned from `fileList.map` is displayed in page.

Another approach using a funciton

```
function getHeaders(fileList) {
let headers = [];

fileList.forEach((titleList) => {
      const title = [];
       title.push(Object.keys(titleList))
        // console.log(title) 
       const head = title.map((item, key) => {
         // console.log(item)
           return <th key={key} scope="col">{item}</th>
        })
        headers = headers.concat(head);
    })
  }
  return headers;
}
```

And in your jsx use this

```
<tr>
   {getHeaders(fileList)}
</tr>
```